# localstack s3 can't accessable from php

Tags: php, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, localstack

I'm trying to work with localstack in my docker container.I created demo-bucket for s3.I can view the file I uploaded from the terminal, but I cannot access s3 from the code. Where am I making a mistake? I share my codes below. Thanks. My yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7" 

services:

php:
  image: php:7.4-fpm
  volumes:
    - ~/image.minyay.com/src:/var/www/html
    - ~/image.minyay.com/docker/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
web:
  image: nginx:1.17
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ~/image.minyay.com/src:/var/www/html
    - ~/image.minyay.com/docker/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  depends_on:
    - php

localstack:
      image: localstack/localstack:0.11.0
      container_name: localstack
      ports:
        - "4563-4599:4563-4599"
        - '8055:8080'
      environment:
        - SERVICES=s3
        - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      volumes:
        - /tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./aws:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d
```

And my php code looks like this:

```
  public function get_big_folder_in_s3($file_path){

        try {
            
           $pages = $this->s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
                'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
                'Prefix' => $file_path, //DESTINATION
            ]);

            foreach ($pages as $page) {
                foreach ($page['Contents'] as $object) {
                  //  echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
                    $result[] = $object['Key'];
                }
            }

            return $result;
            
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {

            return false;
            
        }
    }
```

My s3 client creation:

```
        $this->s3 = S3Client::factory([
            'credentials' => false,
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
            'endpoint' => 'http://localhost:4572',
            'force_path_style'  => true,
        ]);
```

Comment: can you share your s3 client creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you didn't share you client initialization, but localstack usually requires passing an endpoint, thus I guess in PHP I guess it should look something similar to:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'endpoint' => 'http://localstack:4566',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the warning. I think I could not ask the question correctly because I am new to this platform. I updated my question after your warning.

Comment: @Erenözdemir again, if your PHP code is running within the php container, the `endpoint`'s hostname should be `localstack` and not `localhost`

Comment: But i created my bucket like this :aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket
and if i try to aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket
this give an error : Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localstack:4572/"

Comment: did you create the bucket from localhost? (did you run it from your localhost or within some container?). Assuming you created it from the local machine, that's fine. When running things from your local machine use `localhost`. when you're running things within a container - use the `localstack` - both are using the same component, it's just a different name

Comment: Hello again, thank you very much for your interest, I did what you said, but I still can't get any results. I created a github repos to communicate with you more accurately.I would be very grateful if you can review my code and tell me where I went wrong. The steps I followed in the terminal are as follows.
1-Docker-compose up
2- aws --endpoint-url = http: // localhost: 4572 s3 mb s3: // demo-bucket 
3-aws --endpoint-url = http: // localhost: 4572 s3 cp ~ / example.jpg s3: // demo-bucket 
My project link: https: //github.com/erenozdmr/localstacktry   thank you so much again.

Comment: after these steps, I'm trying to access this picture with my functions in index.php.

Comment: and? what's the question?

Comment: You are absolutely right. :) My function enters catch in try-catch structure and I cannot access the image I loaded.

Comment: @Erenözdemir you can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer :)